# Choosing the correct elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am reading in a page with JS that looks like this:

```
<div class="games-fullcol">
  <div class="paginationNav">
    <div class="tableHead" style="background: #1d7225;text-align: center;">PROJECTED 2014     SEASON STATS</div>
      <table class="tableBody" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tableSubHead" bgcolor="#6dbb75" align="right">
          <tr class="tableBody" bgcolor="#f2f2e8" align="right">
          <tr class="tableBody" bgcolor="#f8f8f2" align="right">
            <td align="left">2014 Projections</td>
            <td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>
            <td class="playertableStat ">16/17</td>
            <td class="playertableStat ">12/14</td>
            <td class="playertableStat ">5/7</td>
            <td class="playertableStat ">33/38</td>
            <td class="playertableStat ">55/55</td>
            <td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>
            <td class="playertableStat appliedPoints">171</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="tableBody" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        ...
```

Basically, there's a bunch of these `table.tableBody` elements in side the `div.games-fullcol` element. In each, I want to parse out the text in the `tr.tableBody`. This is what I am trying currently:

```
var $ = window.$;
var table = $("div.games-fullcol");
table.find("table.tableBody").each(function (i, el) {
    var $trs = $(this).find('tr.tableBody').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('background-color') == '#f8f8f2';
    });
    console.log($trs.eq(0).text());
});
```

And right now, that `console.log` prints out a bunch of blank lines (no idea why). I want it to output '2014 Projections'. There must be an issue with how I'm looking for it in the DOM, but I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone find the issue with my logic?

Comment: The HTML for the table is invalid. You can't nest table rows.

Comment: A simple oneliner would do the trick: [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("tbody"), function(x){console.log(x);return x.textContent}).join("\n") http://jsfiddle.net/omc7m3tb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are relaying on the attribute:

```
bgcolor="#f8f8f2"
```

You should change your filter to:

```
return $(this).attr('bgcolor') == "#f8f8f2"
```

At the moment your filter is checking for the css style background-color and not the HMTL attribute bgcolor.

That being said, making your code dependent of the layout style is a very bad idea, why dont you use classes and filter using them?

Comment: Great, thanks for the catch. Will accept when SO allows

Comment: As for your question, I agree that this is a bad idea, although I don't know how I would solve it. I'm scraping this data off the internet, is there a better way to format my JS without having control of the HTML?

Comment: Well if you don't have control over the HTML then there is not much you can do about it